# Updating seed.rb when production is already released

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The best solution I have right is like doing writing it like below.

### Before release of production

`if Category.count == 0
  categories = Category.create([{ name: 'business' }, { name: 'sport' })
end`

### After

```
if Category.count == 0
  categories = Category.create([{ name: 'business' }, { name: 'sport' })
elsif Category.count == 2
  Category.create([{ name: 'science' }])
  categories = Category.all
end
```

This is kinda fail since I have to write `[{ name: 'hoge' }]` everytime I add a data.
And I might miss count the `Category.count === COUNT` which is in the `elsif` block.

Any better solution?

I think it'll be nice if its able to add/remove some value from a certain Array to update the master data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use find_or_create with an array of data:

```
category_data = [
  { name: 'business' },
  { name: 'sport' }
]

category_data.each do |d|
  Category.find_or_create_by(d)
end
```

Edit: sorry, that was the syntax in Rails 4...

```
category_data.each do |d|
  Category.where(d).first_or_create()
end
```

Comment: you mean `find_or_create_by` syntax is for only Rails 4?

Comment: I mean that the documentation for Rails 4 has references to `find_or_create_by`, where the documentation for Rails 3.2 has references to `first_or_create`. Any of them may work in the other setting, but I haven't tried it. In fact I remember having used something similar to `find_or_create_by_name` in a Rails 2.3 application.

Comment: Not considering possible cascades, you'll have to query something like `Category.where("name NOT IN (?)", category_data.map {|i| i[:name] }).each(&:destroy)`.

Comment: I c. how about truncating the table first, then inserting all the datas from the hash?

Comment: You may end with broken associations, like if your Category#4 is Something, then you truncate and seed it again, the sequence is reset and the Category#4 may end being SomethingElse, so all the associated objects will change categories....

Comment: I c. So basically we shouldn't delete a data from seeds, so basically we dont have to think about the deletions?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use something like [seed_fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) to manage seed data. I also add a rake task to execute the seeds on each deploy.